# Define range of top position in CSS layout

Tags: html, css, properties

I have redefined the H2 tag in two classes with CSS. In one class, the H2 tag should have a top position of 6vw and the other H2 should be placed below (8.5vw):

```
.slide .first h2 {
   color: #006666;
   font-size: 2vw;
   width: auto;
   top: 6vw;
   white-space: nowrap;
   z-index: 10;
   font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   font-weight: 700;
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
   padding-left: 5px;
   padding-right: 5px;
}

.slide .second h2 {
   color: #006666;
   font-size: 2vw;
   width: auto;
   top: 8.5vw;
   white-space: nowrap;
   z-index: 10;
   font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   font-weight: 700;
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
   padding-left: 5px;
   padding-right: 5px;
}
```

My goal is to have a min top position of 60px for the first class. Using max(6vw, 60px) works pretty well but for the second class I'm not sure what I should use. max(8.5vw, 90px) doesn't work as it assumes the exact same position as for the first class, placed above.

Comment: Please provide the code that demonstrates the problem. A JFiddle might help.

Comment: Also, is seems you are pointing two different styles to the same element...is there JS involved someplace?

Comment: can you post the html or a [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)?